# Flipping D3DX10_SPRITE over one axis doesn't work, flipping both works

Tags: c++, directx, transform, sprite

I'm making a 2D sidescrolling game(DirectX 10), so I'd like to flip sprites over the Y axis. For some reason the sprite doesn't draw when I specify a negative scaling value in either Y or X direction, but if I specify positive or negative scaling values for both, it draws just fine. I don't think it's a case of the sprite being offscreen, since I've checked the values in matWorld and it's always within the values of my viewport.

The code that sets up matWorld is as follows:

```
D3DXMATRIX matTranslation;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslation, static_cast<float>(m_X), static_cast<float>(m_Y), m_Z );

D3DXMATRIX matTranslationPointMove;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslationPointMove, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f); 

D3DXMATRIX matScaling;
D3DXMatrixScaling(&matScaling, static_cast<float>(m_Width) * m_ScaleX, static_cast<float>(m_Height) * m_ScaleY, 1.0f);

m_Sprite.matWorld = matTranslationPointMove * matScaling * matTranslation;
```

For some different scaling values, matWorld looks like this(apologies for formatting..):

```
ScaleX=ScaleY = 1 ---- ScaleX=ScaleY = -1 ------------ ScaleX=-1, ScaleY=1


[24 0 0 0] ---------------- [-24 0 0 0] ------------------------ [-24 0 0 0 ]

[0 18 0 0] ---------------- [0 -18 0 0] ------------------------ [0 18 0 0 ]

[0 0 1 0 ] ----------------- [0 0 1 0  ] ------------------------- [0 0 1 0 ]

[12 52 0.6 1 ] ----------- [-12 52 0.6 1 ] ------------------- [-12 52 0.6 1 ]
```

The drawing code looks like this:

```
m_pDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(m_pRenderTargetView, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
HRESULT hr = NULL;

D3DXMATRIX matProjection;
D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&matProjection,
    -400.0f,
    800.0f,
    -400.0f,
    800.0f,
    0.1f,
    10.0f
);

hr = m_ISprite->SetProjectionTransform(&matProjection);
if (FAILED(hr)) OutputDebugStringA("NOOooooo");

m_ISprite->Begin(D3DX10_SPRITE_SORT_DEPTH_BACK_TO_FRONT);
spriteVector::iterator it = spritesToDraw.begin();
while( it != spritesToDraw.end() )
{
    m_ISprite->DrawSpritesBuffered(*it, 1);
    ++it;
}
m_ISprite->Flush();
m_ISprite->End();
m_pSwapChain->Present(0,0);
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong, all the values seem normal to me. What am I doing wrong, or is there another way to do it? It'd be a sad day if I have to animate all sprites in reverse by hand, too.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the same thing happen on different hardware or with the software renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild, untested theory:

- the sprite is rendered as a textured polygon in 3D space
- flipping it turns the backside to the camera
- the 3D rendering is set up to ignore backsides

Comment: Holy... I would _NEVER_ have thought of that, but that was actually the case. I turned off culling and bam it works. Thank you very much!